# PHP Set Variable to Array Key in One Line

Tags: php, arrays, variables, key

This is going to be a very simple question, I have code that looks like this:

```
<?php
$rawmessage = "This is what I want.--This is all junk.";

$fmessage = explode("--", $rawmessage);
//Alt. Universe #1: $fmessage = $fmessage[0];

echo $fmessage[0]; //"This is what I want."
//Alt. Universe #1: echo $fmessage;
?>
```

Now I know how stupid this may sound, but is there a way I can assign $fmessage to [0] in one line? Because 1) I don't want to write $fmessage[0], it doesn't need to be an array at this point, and 2) I want to know if this is doable because this isn't the first time I've wanted to set only one part of the array to a variable. Example of what I want to write (in my fantasy land, of course. This throws an error in reality.)

```
<?php
$rawmessage = "This is what I want.--This is all junk.";

$fmessage = explode("--", $rawmessage)[0];
//In my fantasy land, adding the [0] means that the array's key [0] value is set to $fmessage

echo $fmessage; //"This is what I want." For real.
?>
```

Comment: Your fantasy land array dereferencing actually works with the latest code in the PHP trunk, so maybe that feature will show up in PHP 5.4.

Comment: @konorce About friggin' time!

Comment: Say wha? I should be a PHP developer if I'm thinking that ahead! :P

Comment: You can only be a PHP dev if you consider using a `:)` for a [namespace separator](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/namespaceseparator) :P

Comment: @alex I had to think real hard to make up the `--`! And also, http://bit.ly/bBwlZw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list($fmessage) = explode('--', $rawmessage);
```

`list()` isn't a function, but a PHP language construct (or just an operator that looks like a function).

It will unpack array members into local variables...

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');

list($a, $b, $c) = $array;

var_dump($a, $b, $c);
```

Outputs...

```
string(1) "a"
string(1) "b"
string(1) "c"
```

Comment: You're too damn quick! ;-) +1

Comment: That was incredibly fast O_O. Just so I'm clear though, should I be expecting a visit from the PHP developers and receive a slap on the wrist for bad practice or is this A-OH-KAY?

Comment: @NessDan This is fine, so long as you don't abuse it. Basically this is a terser version of your posted code, with the same result at the end, so that is OK.